# grpc: received message larger than max (8653851 vs. 4194304)

Tags: go, grpc, grpc-go

**The problem**:

I am getting this error while receiving message in grpc:

`rpc error: code = ResourceExhausted desc = grpc: received message larger than max (8653851 vs. 4194304)`

**What I tried:**

I gave the option to increase the size of the message to be received but it still gave the same error which means this setting of maximum size didn't work:

```
size := 1024 * 1024 * 12
opts = append(opts, grpc.WithDefaultCallOptions(grpc.MaxCallRecvMsgSize(size)))
conn, err := grpc.Dial(address, opts...)
```

**Comments:**

The default limit is `1024 * 1024 * 4 = 4194304` which is shown in the error message. I was expecting this limit to increase to `1024 * 1024 * 12 = 12582912` but clearly it didn't.

Comment: Strange, works for me. Can you reduce this to a complete reproducible example?

Answer (score 10):

Please try updating [grpc.MaxCallSendMsgSize(s int)](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/grpc#MaxCallSendMsgSize) on your client to enable your client send larger message.
This worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

Call options can be passed with each request.

For example, if your package is called `queue` and your method is called `GetItems`, then you would pass in the `MaxCallRecvMsgSize` option when calling `GetItems`.

Protobuf:

```proto
package queue;

service Queue {
    rpc GetItems (Request) returns (Items) {
    }
}
```

Go:

```golang
conn, err := grpc.Dial(address, opts...)
c := queue.NewQueueClient(s.Conn)
maxSizeOption := grpc.MaxCallRecvMsgSize(32*10e6)
items, err := c.GetItems(ctx, &queue.Request{}, maxSizeOption)
```

Answer (score 0):

I met the same question. My DialOption below sets MaxCallRecvMsgSize to be math.MaxInt64. But it doesn't work.

The reason is **grpc.WithChainUnaryInterceptor(chains...)** appended will be executed firstly when the client call GRPC functons, and the client will jump over the grpc.WithDefaultCallOptions. So you should set **MaxCallRecvMsgSize** in chains or remove **grpc.WithChainUnaryInterceptor**.

```
func NewClient() (promotion.PromotionClient, error) {
    conn, err := grpc.Dial("address", DialogOptions()...)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return promotion.NewPromotionClient(conn), nil
}

func DialogOptions(chains ...grpc.UnaryClientInterceptor) []grpc.DialOption {
    chains = append(chains, userinfo.UnaryClientInterceptor())
    return []grpc.DialOption{
        grpc.WithDefaultCallOptions(
            grpc.MaxCallRecvMsgSize(math.MaxInt64),
            grpc.MaxCallSendMsgSize(math.MaxInt64),
        ),
        grpc.WithChainUnaryInterceptor(chains...),
    }
}
```